# Create an invoice in the Basware

Tags: testing, finance, web-api-testing, invoice

I want to create an invoice via Basware test API v1, here is the link -> https://network-developer.basware.com/api-v1.html

I'm using this endpoint 'https://test-api.basware.com/v1/invoices/{bumId}', and do POST request, but I'm getting an '401 Unauthorized' error, but if I will change the endpoint to 'https://test-api.basware.com/v1/account',  and do GET request, it will work.

Does anyone have experience with the Basware test API to create an invoice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.